# C# HttpClient failing to make GET requests with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Api application with the following configuration of HttpClient. In Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

services.AddHttpClient("myapi", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["endpoint"]);
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
       new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
          IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Convert.ToBase64String(
             System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{Configuration["username"]}:{Configuration["password"]}")));
});
```

I then try to make an HTTP call like this:

```
var client = clientFactory.CreateClient(clientName);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);            
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)            
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

however I always get an Unauthorized response when calling an internal api. Under Debug I have Windows authentication and Anonymous authentication both enabled.
With Postman my api calls go through, which verifies that I got the right credentials.
Can you suggest any alterations to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =`, I'm having config like this

```
c.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
{
  Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"),
  AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
  PreAuthenticate = true
});
```

I guess this will not work as-is in your case, but I hope this can get you on track.